# citations in Pandoc footnotes rendered as numerals

Tags: latex, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I am getting a weird result when I convert markdown to PDF using Pandoc. This is for academic writing with footnotes generated via citeproc; a bibtex library generated by Zotero; and a Chicago csl file. Most of the footnotes are fine, but sometimes where I should see a book or article I just get a numeral.

When I write the following in Markdown

`^[@melvilleMobyDick, 155]`

I want a footnote that says

> Herman Melville, *Moby-Dick,* p. 155

but I get

> 1, p. 155

The problem seems to be in the transition from markdown to LaTeX; the latter output is:

```
\footnote{1, 155}
```

My shell command is:

```
$ pandoc article.md -o article.latex --filter=pandoc-citeproc
```

And I am using this YAML header:

```
title: Essay
bibliography: My_Library.bib
csl: chicago_fullnote_ibid.csl
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `chicago_fullnote_ibid.csl`, which styles citations as footnotes. So just do `[@melvilleMobyDick, 155]` instead of `^[@melvilleMobyDick, 155]` and it will turn into a footnote.

Comment: Thank you for the response.